# Unpredictable behaviour of the QSPI clocks while accessing QSPI read

Tags: c, embedded-linux

I'm trying to read the data from the slave using QSPI as an interface.When I verified with the clock cycles that are being occurred I can see there more clock cycles than I expected i.e., for example I want to read the data of 1 byte using four lines the no.of clock cycles will be 2 cycles but I was seeing around 16 clock cycles.
What could be the reason of this extra clock cycles addition and how to overcome this issue

Note: The slave device is FPGA in my case i.e., QSPI acts as interface in between the sama5d27 processor and FPGA

Comment: Do you see additional clock cycles after the slave put the data byte on the lines or just additional clock cycles for complete read command ? Is there opcode and address information for read command defined which is setup by master before slave puts data on lines ? From my experience with SPI Flash Memory and EEPROM slave devices read command consists of opcode and address setup by master and data setup by slave.

Comment: I can see additional clocks whenever I set the dataenable bit in the register nothing but whenever I am trying to receive  the data from the slave .For Opcode and Address information alone the no of cycles that are occurring as expected on 4 lines.Yes there is an opcode and address information .